# loading the TensorBoard notebook extension suddenly fails in a Colab notebook

Tags: tensorboard, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

Loading the TensorBoard notebook extension fails suddenly.

Following the Colab example: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb

Tried restarting the runtime, had no effect.

```py
!pip install -q tf-nightly-2.0-preview
# Load the TensorBoard notebook extension
%load_ext tensorboard
```

Actual result:

`The tensorboard module is not an IPython extension.`

I can't even find any other reference to this error return.

Answer (score 4):

Use `%load_ext tensorboard.notebook` instead. This will work. It is an already raised Issue on gitHub.